# c# extension not working in VSCode in Linux

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I am a Kubuntu user. I downloaded VSCode to program in Unity and added the C# Extension for autocompletion as an IDE. But for some reason I get this error:

Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

I entered in the page to install the .NET Framework Developer Packs as it says but seems that is only for Windows.

Note that I already installed Mono and .NET as I saw in another question. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: It doesn't look like an issue with the extension itself, looks like your project targets .net framework - which definitely wouldn't work because .net framework is windows only.

Comment: okay, so what would you recommend? should I try with another extension?